# Chance for a Tourist visa after abandoning GC application

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, tourist-visas

I applied for a Green Card for my parent based on family petition i-130 but she had to leave United states before her interview happened as she changed her mind about “immigrating” to the United States. Her previous tourist visa ended. I130 and I485 got stuck in "processing" not approved nor denied.

I wonder if we cancel and withdraw the entire application can she still apply for a visitor visa and have it approved if we explain that she does not have immigration intent?

Comment: Generally speaking, withdrawn visa applications are completely neutral, they do not have a positive or negative impact on future visa applications.  But US green cards are weird enough that I'll let someone with actual expertise answer.

Comment: Was she granted an Advance Parole before she left?